# Delete all <li> and </li> tags inside ul class

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to delete all `<li>` and `</li>` tags inside ul class in notepad++ 
here is example:

```
<ul class="test">

    <li>
        <img title="test" alt="test" src="http://test.jpg" width="50" height="50">
    </li>

    <li>
        <img title="test" alt="test" src="test" width="50" height="50">
    </li>

</ul>
```

to achieve this:

```
<ul class="test">

        <img title="test" alt="test" src="http://test.jpg" width="50" height="50">

        <img title="test" alt="test" src="test" width="50" height="50">       

</ul>
```

Comment: Show us your attempt(s)

Comment: Why do you want to mutilate it so? What did it ever do to you?

Comment: You know the result is a misuse of the HTML5 spec right? Quoting the [W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) : `Content model: Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.` (a script-supporting element should have no visual representation)

Comment: You may try XSLT if your HTML is structured like XHTML. Otherwise, regexp is your choice for sure (to not write your own "velosip'ed")

Comment: @Aaron ul class will be deleted after replacing <li>

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve my problem: 
Serach for

- `((?-s)<ul.+test(?s).+?)<li>` and
- `((?-s)<ul.+test(?s).+?)</li>`

replace it by `\1`

Comment: You risk removing `li`s from further `ul`s since `.+?` will happily consume closing `ul` tags and whatever follows up to the next `li`. This could be fixed by using a negative lookahead instead, such as `(?:[^<]|<(?!/ul))+?`. This removes the need for the `s`ingle-line flag which only specifies what `.` matches and has no effect for more complex classes. Also you can merge both regex into one, so I suggest `(<ul.+test(?:[^<]|<(?!/ul))+?)<\/?li>` as a improvment.

Comment: concerning the removal of the `s` flag : don't do it if your `class="test"` could be on another line that the `<ul` (or also replace the first `.+` by something more specific like `[^>]+`). I'd match the whole `\bclass="test"\b` too if I were you.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron for your help. This is much better solution!